# I keep getting a ImportError: cannot import name 'accounts' on python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm developing a script to manipulate accounts in a application using its API. In my enviroment runs perfectly, but when I tried to use in a linux red hat enviroment a error appear saying that it can't import a module.

My import:

```
etc...
from Pyway import accounts as stlib
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "script.py", line 15, in <module>
     from Pyway import accounts as stlib
ImportError: cannot import name 'accounts'
```

Comment: Where did this `Pyway` module come from?  The only thing of that name I can find online contains absolutely nothing named `accounts`.

Comment: As mentioned, most of us don't know what "Pyway" is. It seems like you have different packages installed in these two environment. But without any information about what this thing is, there isn't much we can do.